# Building dynamic lists of billboard.js charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JSON list whose elements are the properties of a series of charts. I would like to use D3 and billboard.js to dynamically generate a list of HTML `div` elements, each of which contain one chart. The setup is shown at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abielr/np70vdj3/). While the charts appear, I get a number of D3 errors like `Error: <g> attribute transform: Trailing garbage, "translate(0,NaN)".` and the billboard.js charts have weird `[object Object]` strings appearing next to the axis. These errors would not appear if for instance I had manually created named `div` elements in the HTML and then bound the billboard.js charts to these.

Comment: The `[object Object]` usually means you are trying to print out the whole object rather than a property or function of the object. Do you have some code examples?

Comment: See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abielr/np70vdj3/) mentioned in the original posting for the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because of data bound on the chart DOM element.
Just remove data bound and will solve the issue.

Just add `d3.select(this).datum(null);` on iteration block.
Check out the result running the snippet.

```js
var cdata = [
 {
  title: "Chart1",
  data: {
   columns: [
    ["data1", 10, 20, 30],
    ["data2", 50, 20, 10]
   ]
  }
 },
 {
  title: "Chart2",
  data: {
   columns: [
    ["data1", 10, 20, 30],
    ["data2", 50, 20, 10]
   ]
  }
 }
];

d3.select("#container").selectAll("div")
    .data(cdata)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("width", 200)
    .style("height", 200)
    .each(function(d) {
        // remove data set on DOM element
     d3.select(this).datum(null);

        bb.generate({
         data: d.data,
         title: { text: d.title },
         bindto: this
        });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```